# Do I have to be worried about copyright infringement when digitally copying and collecting excerpts from published literature?

Tags: research-process

I can't find any information regarding this scenario. Related answers are always about publishing said excerpts in one's own works, and my question is specifically about copied texts that are never going to be published. My initial thought was that it was surely fine to do so, but the current book I'm working through is so dense in information that I've probably digitally recreated half of the book, and that got me thinking, and has lead to this question.

Comment: See the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement, which is primarily a US view. And it may be an ethical violation even if it isn't technically copyright infringement.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the collected material?

Comment: @Alchimista i'm only collecting it for research purposes. when i'm done, and have all the references i need sorted out, i can discard it all.

Comment: I do not see what is the matter, then.